Dialogflow cx add multiple actions to a button
I am building a chatbot that is connected to google chat app.I want to have a button that opens a url for the end user when he click on it AND helps me move onto my next page, however 2 actions seem not to be allowed on 1 button in cards v2.
The custom payload would look something like this
{
                      "text": "TEST",
                      "onClick": {
                        "openLink": {
                          "url": "https://www.example.com" 
                        },
                        "action": {
                          "function": "MOVE_TO_NEXT_PAGE" 
                        }
                      }
                    }

Tried putting multiple actions but it did not work, I cannot use webhooks for this.
